# Grizzly 2.3.11 + Atmosphere 2.1.3: getServletPath() returns null

Tags: atmosphere, grizzly

I'm testing Atmosphere 2.1.3 using Grizzly 2.3.11. I've created a *ManagedService(path="/chat")*, but I get this error: 'No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /chat Status 500 Message Server Error'. If I change the path to *ManagedService(path="/")* it works. I've debugged a bit and it seems that org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequest.getServletPath() returns null, so a default path "/" is used and that's the cause that makes my test work using *ManagedService(path="/")*.

I'll appreciate your help because I need to use a path kinda ManagedService(path="/chat").

NOTE: this post is related to [Atmosphere + Grizzly: No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /chat Status 500 Message Server Error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/atmosphere-framework/hPTOz1ClXUw)

PD: This is my Main test class:

```
package com.dweb.atmosphere.grizzly;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.atmosphere.container.Grizzly2CometSupport;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.comet.CometAddOn;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketAddOn;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(".", 8181);

        final WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("ctx", "/");

        // enable web socket support
        final WebSocketAddOn addon = new WebSocketAddOn();

        for (NetworkListener listener : server.getListeners()) {
            listener.registerAddOn(addon);
        }

        // add atmosphere servlet support
        final AtmosphereServlet atmosphereServlet = new AtmosphereServlet();.

        final ServletRegistration atmosphereServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("AtmosphereServlet", atmosphereServlet);

        atmosphereServletRegistration.setInitParameter(
                "org.atmosphere.websocket.messageContentType",
                "application/json");
        atmosphereServletRegistration.addMapping("/chat/*");
        atmosphereServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        // deploy
        ctx.deploy(server);

        try {
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Press enter to stop the server...");
            System.in.read();
        } finally {
            server.shutdownNow();
        }  
    }
}
```

PD2: This is my ChatRoom test class:

```
package com.dweb.atmosphere.grizzly;

import static org.atmosphere.cpr.ApplicationConfig.MAX_INACTIVE;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.Disconnect;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.Get;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService;
import org.atmosphere.config.service.Ready;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResource;
import org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * Simple annotated class that demonstrate the power of Atmosphere. This class supports all transports, support
 * message length garantee, heart beat, message cache thanks to the {@link ManagedService}.
 */
@Config
@ManagedService(path = "/chat", atmosphereConfig = MAX_INACTIVE + "=120000")
public class ChatRoom {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChatRoom.class);

    /**
     * Invoked when the connection as been fully established and suspended, e.g ready for receiving messages.
     *
     * @param r
     */
    @Ready
    public void onReady(final AtmosphereResource r) {
        logger.debug("Browser {} connected.", r.uuid());
    }

    /**
     * Invoked when the client disconnect or when an unexpected closing of the underlying connection happens.
     *
     * @param event
     */
    @Disconnect
    public void onDisconnect(AtmosphereResourceEvent event) {
        if (event.isCancelled()) {
            logger.info("Browser {} unexpectedly disconnected", event.getResource().uuid());
        } else if (event.isClosedByClient()) {
            logger.info("Browser {} closed the connection", event.getResource().uuid());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Simple annotated class that demonstrate how {@link org.atmosphere.config.managed.Encoder} and {@link org.atmosphere.config.managed.Decoder
     * can be used.
     *
     * @param message an instance of {@link Message}
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @org.atmosphere.config.service.Message
    public String onMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        logger.info("just send() {}", message);
        return message;
    }

}
```

PD3: this is my server log

```
Apr 23, 2014 2:16:46 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext deploy
INFO: Starting application [ctx] ...
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$BytecodeBasedAnnotationProcessor being used
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - Found Annotation in com.dweb.atmosphere.grizzly.ChatAtmosphereHandler being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.service.AtmosphereHandlerService
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereHandler com.dweb.atmosphere.grizzly.ChatAtmosphereHandler mapped to context-path /chat2 and Broadcaster Class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - Found Annotation in com.dweb.atmosphere.grizzly.ChatRoom being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereHandler org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler mapped to context-path /chat and Broadcaster Class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor [@ManagedService Interceptor, Atmosphere LifeCycle,  Track Message Size Interceptor using |, UUID Tracking Interceptor] mapped to AtmosphereHandler org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - Found Annotation in com.dweb.atmosphere.grizzly.Chat being scanned: interface org.atmosphere.config.service.ManagedService
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereHandler org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler mapped to context-path /chatzz and Broadcaster Class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed AtmosphereInterceptor [@ManagedService Interceptor, Atmosphere LifeCycle,  Track Message Size Interceptor using |, UUID Tracking Interceptor] mapped to AtmosphereHandler org.atmosphere.config.managed.ManagedAtmosphereHandler
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptor
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor : Heartbeat Interceptor Support
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using BroadcasterCache: org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Shared ExecutorService supported: true
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - HttpSession supported: false
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport running under container: Grizzly 2.3.11 with WebSocket enabled.
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Atmosphere Framework 2.1.3 started.
[main] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - 

    For Atmosphere Framework Commercial Support, visit 
    http://www.async-io.org/ or send an email to support@async-io.org

Apr 23, 2014 2:16:46 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext initServlets
INFO: [ctx] Servlet [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet] registered for url pattern(s) [[/chat/*]].
Apr 23, 2014 2:16:46 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.WebappContext deploy
INFO: Application [ctx] is ready to service requests.  Root: [/].
Apr 23, 2014 2:16:46 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]
Apr 23, 2014 2:16:46 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
Press enter to stop the server...
[Thread-1] INFO org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.1.5
[Grizzly(7) SelectorRunner] WARN org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor - Failed invoking AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport()
org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /chat
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.map(AsynchronousProcessor.java:329)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:133)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:95)
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:60)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:1805)
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:432)
    at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.open(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:186)
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport$Grizzly2WebSocketApplication.onConnect(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.SimpleWebSocket.onConnect(SimpleWebSocket.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketEngine.upgrade(WebSocketEngine.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketEngine.upgrade(WebSocketEngine.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketFilter.doServerUpgrade(WebSocketFilter.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketFilter.handleServerHandshake(WebSocketFilter.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketFilter.handleHandshake(WebSocketFilter.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.BaseWebSocketFilter.handleRead(BaseWebSocketFilter.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:550)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.SameThreadIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(SameThreadIOStrategy.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:412)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:276)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[Grizzly(7) SelectorRunner] WARN org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol - org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /chat Status 500 Message Server Error
```

Hi Alexey,

I'm debugging this issue, these are my tests & results:

-. When I call '`http://localhost:8181/chat/a/b/c`' internally this request is built: '`AtmosphereRequest{ contextPath= servletPath=/chat pathInfo=/a/b/c requestURI=/chat/a/b/c destroyable=true}`'     Well, Http Get requests seem to work fine.

-. When I call '`new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8181/chat/a/b/c')`' internally this request is built '`AtmosphereRequest{ contextPath= servletPath=null pathInfo=null requestURI=/chat/a/b/c destroyable=true}`'     I think the problem (servletPath & pathInfo are null) only happens when I use websockets

I'm debbuging the method org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.WebSocketEngine.upgrade(FilterChainContext ctx, HttpContent requestContent, Mapper mapper) and the param requestContent receives this value:

```
HttpRequestPacket (
   method=GET
   url=/chat/a/b/c
   query=null
   protocol=HTTP/1.1
   content-length=-1
   headers=[
      upgrade=websocket
      connection=Upgrade
      host=localhost:8181
      origin=http://localhost:8080
      pragma=no-cache
      cache-control=no-cache
      sec-websocket-key=3pRm4vKnwqvRO8G0/WUNBw==
      sec-websocket-version=13
      sec-websocket-extensions=permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
      user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36]
)
```

but at the end of my debugging session the method org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper.computePath(AtmosphereRequest req) receives the param req with this value: AtmosphereRequest{ contextPath= servletPath=null pathInfo=null requestURI=/chat/a/b/c destroyable=true}

Well I hope these tests have some value for you, anyway if you need more tests feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was found and fixed in Grizzly 2.3.12.

https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1680
The code should work as it is.

Comment: I've included the results of my latest tests

Comment: Hi Alexey, I've tested your changes and now this issue is fixed. Thanks for your support.
PD: sorry I can't vote your answer cos I'm a new user and my reputation is low.